# Java abstract class with generic parameter that implements its own generic parameter

Tags: java, class, generics, interface, abstract

I'm facing a tricky problem.
I'm trying to do create a callback manager generic class that takes a generic of any kind of interfaces. The plan is, to do something like that:

```
public interface LocationListener {
    void locationChanged();
    void providerChanged();
}

//The implementation declaration below is wrong...
public abstract class CallbackManager<T> implements T {
    //do something
}

public class MyCallbackManager extends CallbackManager<LocationListener> {

   @Override
   public void locationChanged() {

   } 

   @Override
   public void providerChanged() {

   }
}
```

Generally spoken, I try to avoid to build the MyCallbackManager class like that:

```
public class MyCallbackManager extends CallbackManager<LocationListener> implements LocationListener {

   @Override
   public void locationChanged() {

   } 

   @Override
   public void providerChanged() {

   }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve that? 
I'm looking forward to your responses.

**EDIT**

Because you asked for a clarification of the use case. This is the idea behind it:

```
public abstract class CallbackManager<T>  {

    protected interface FunctionalInterface<T> {
        void run(T type);
    }

    protected ArrayList<WeakReference<T>> eventQueue = new ArrayList<>();

    protected void flush(@NonNull FunctionalInterface<T> functionalInterface) {
        for (int i = eventQueue.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            WeakReference<T> weakReference = eventQueue.get(i);
            T type = weakReference.get();
            if (type == null) {
                unregister(i);
            } else {
                functionalInterface.run(type);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class CallbackManagerLocation extends CallbackManager<LocationListener> implements LocationListener {

   @Override
   public void locationChanged() {
        flush((ll) -> ll.locationChanged());
   } 

   @Override
   public void providerChanged() {
        flush((ll) -> ll.providerChanged());
   }
}
```

The implemented interface in CallbackManagerLocation is only used to have exactly the same naming convention like the interface that is hold in the CallbackManager.

Comment: "`public abstract class CallbackManager<T> implements T {`" No, you can't do this.

Comment: What do you use the type parameter for?

Comment: As you found, `class CallbackManager<T> implements T` is not possible. But what kind of methods would have `CallbackManager`? Are you sure you need a superclass?

Comment: Changing a type parameter can't cause the class to require different methods. That's nonsense. You're over complicating

Comment: I think we may be able to help you better if you explain what behavior in the `CallbackManager` needs to be inherited, and how it relates to the `T`.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a second example of a class that extends CallbackManager, with a different generic type.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your responses. I edited my post

Comment: I am not sure that you actually need the type differentiation in the `CallbackManager` at all. What do you lose by defining the weak references on `Object` instead of `T`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but this is not allowed. The amount of problems resulting from this would be enormous. For example imagine if you had a function `public T locationChanged()` in CallbackManager. This would violate the interface without being obvious in the CallbackManager class. And a lot more such examples.

Comment: @findul yes, I see. I edited my question. As you can see, I'm not calling the methods of the interface inside the CallbackManager. The CallbackManager only holds the references of the interfaces. The call is done in the class, that extends the CallbackManager (e.g. CallbackManagerLocation).

Answer (score 1):

No, You cannot do like that,

`public abstract class CallbackManager<T> implements T`

It will throw compile time error as class T is not describing actual type of reference that is implemented by your abstract class as per class loading mechanism provided in JAVA doc.

There is another way so you can do as follow,
`public abstract class CallbackManager<ParentListener> implements ParentListener`.

but you will get error message like `Cannot refer to the type parameter LocationListener as a supertype`
And it is not needed in any scenario, If exists there is alternate way for its answer